# Sqlite3 - Multiple results into separate columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am new to SQL and need some help with selecting multiple results for a given value into different columns.

Part of my table looks something like this -

```
DevID   ConnID   Other Columns ...
 D1       Q1  
 D1       Q1
 D1       Q1
 D1       Q2
 D1       Q2
 D1       Q2
 D2       Q3  
 D2       Q3
 D2       Q3
 D2       Q4
 D2       Q4
 D2       Q4
...       ...
```

I want the resultant SELECT query to be -

```
DevID    PrimConnID    SecConnID  OtherColumns ...
 D1         Q1            Q2
 D2         Q3            Q4
...         ...           ...            ...
```

Is this possible using standard SQL? Aplologies if it is not clear - I really am a novice.

Comment: How many different values can the `ConnID` column have?  You are probably looking for a pivot query, but the exact answer will depend on the answer to my question.

Comment: There are over 100 different values for `ConnID`

Comment: You need to show a sample data set which demonstrates what the full scale problem will be.  Do you always want only two columns, or would there be 100 columns in the result set?

Comment: Only 2 columns maximum. Each DevID connects to one or two ConnID devices - the primary and the secondary. There is other data in the table making each of the six instances of D1 in the example unique.

Comment: I've edited the question example to try to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.ConnID) 
            FROM #YourTableName c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DevID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select DevID
                ,ConnID
                from #YourTableName
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(ConnID)
                for ConnID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks Newton, but there are over 100 different ConnID values, and each DevID can have any 2 of them as PrimConnID and SecConnID.  There are about 150 DevID values.

Comment: Then this should do it:

Comment: Thanks Newton. Trying this out now. Getting syntax errors for DECLARE. I'll play around with it to see if I can get it to work - and read up on setting and declaring variables in SQL.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT AA.DevID
 ,AA.ConnID PrimConnID
 ,BB.ConnID SecConnID
FROM #YourTableName AA
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT DevID
  ,ConnID
 FROM #YourTableName
 ) BB ON AA.DevID = BB.DevID
 AND AA.ConnID <> BB.ConnID
WHERE AA.ConnID < BB.ConnID

Comment: Newton, thanks - did one worked! I appreciate your assistance. It missed some records for some reason, but I should be able to work it out from here. Thank you again.